# Change data with buttonclick - MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a ListView with an `List<List<enum>>` property and i have a View that shows each bool as button.

I want to cycle through the bound enum when someone clicks on the button. The problem is I cant use a normal click because it would be outside of my ViewModel.

Edit:

I have the class TruthTable that has 2 DynTable:

```
public sealed class Column<T>
{
    public Column()
    {
        ColumnData = new List<T>();
        ColumnHeader = "";
    }

    ...

    public List<T> ColumnData { get; set; }
    public string ColumnHeader { get; set; }
}

public sealed class DynTable<T>
{
    public DynTable()
    {
        Columns = new List<Column<T>>();
    }

    ...

    public List<Column<T>> Columns { get; set; }
}

public sealed class TruthTable
{
    public TruthTable()
    {
        input = new DynTable<bool>();
        results = new DynTable<BoolState>();
    }

    ...

    private DynTable<bool> input;
    private DynTable<BoolState> results;

    public DynTable<bool> Input { get { return input; } set { input = value; } }
    public DynTable<BoolState> Results { get { return results; }}
}

public enum BoolState
{
    False = 0,
    True = 1,
    DontCare = 2
}
```

And i have a ViewModel for the TruthTable. I dont think that the I have to show the code for the ViewModel because its just a TruthTable property. I hope thats enough code to understand my problem ._.

Comment: Can you add some sample code?

Comment: You may be interested in exposing an ICommand property in your ViewModel to handle the button click.